# how to fetch keys of dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm using a `Dictionary<char, ulong>` where the char is a obj no, & ulong is offset.

Now, I need to access the Keys of Dictionary. Keys is any random number which cant predict.
I am using VS-2005. 
I am new to C# so plz provide some code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Matt says, the [`Keys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk.aspx) property is your friend. This returns a [`KeyCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fcwy8h6.aspx), but usually you just want to iterate over it:

```
foreach (char key in dictionary.Keys)
{
    // Whatever
}
```

Note that the order in which the keys are returned is not guaranteed. In many cases it will actually be insertion order, but you must *not* rely on that.

I'm slightly concerned that you talk about the keys being random *numbers* when it looks like they're *characters*. Have you definitely chosen the right types here?

One more tip - if you will sometimes need the values as well as the keys, you can iterate over the `KeyValuePair`s in the dictionary too:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<char, ulong> pair in dictionary)
{
    char c = pair.Key;
    ulong x = pair.Value;
    ...
}
```

Comment: shouldn't that be foreach(char key in dictionary.Keys), Jon?

Comment: so this is why you and Marc have got such a high rep! Nice answers - if I update mine now it'll just look like I'm copying.

Comment: @Marc: Yes, I edited a couple of times. Did you answer as well? I didn't see it. @Shoko: Yes, I fixed that in the first edit. I was remembering the "number" part of the post, which was why I assumed it was ulong as the key. Then when I posted it, I spotted the mistake and edited.

Answer (score 3):

Dictionary provides a Keys property that contains all of the keys in the dictionary.